# Testing custom StyleCop rules: Call to AddSourceFile() always returns false when using ReSharper testrunner

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resharper, stylecop

I asked this question in the [StyleCop forum](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/discussions/474239) but never got an answer.

---

I found lots of examples for testing custom rules using MSTest and I got [that one](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2009/09/21/custom-stylecop-rules-part-ii/) to work easily enough.

But these tests don't work when using the ReSharper testrunner. For some reason the call to

```
StyleCopConsole.Core.Environment.AddSourceFile(...)
```

always returns false whenever I use something other than VS 2010's built-in testrunner via the *Test View*. As that *Test View* is possibly the least user-friendly tool I ever had to use for running tests I would prefer to use ReSharper. A lot.

I have a sub-folder inside my test assembly called Resources which contains the invalid source files for my tests and the *Settings.StyleCop* file. They are copied to the test output folder correctly (I added an extra check using `File.Exists` prior to calling *AddSourceFile(...)* to make sure of that).

I added references to *StyleCop.dll, StyleCop.CSharp.dll and StyleCop.CSharp.Rules.dll* which did not solve the problem.

Using the ReSharper runner the *StyleCopCore.Parsers* collection is always empty. When I use the VS runner it contains a *CsParser*.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: How do you get the path to the file? Is that a relative path? Try running `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and writing the outcome to see what the base folder looks like. Plus, you did regsiter a `Parser` object for the file extension, right? (more hints may be found here: https://stylecop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Project/Src/StyleCop/FileBasedEnvironment.cs)

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks for the hint. I manually added a CsParser and now AddSourceFile works. But it ignores my custom rules.

Comment: That's step one :). I have no clue why your rule would not get triggered now... But I think I answered your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StyleCopConsole.Core.Environment` expects that you've registered a parser for the file extension you're feeding to it. So you probably want to add a `CsParser` instance to the Parsers collection and set the extension to `.cs`.

Luckily the sources for StyleCop are available so it pays off to check why a code path might return false and see whether that precondition has been passed.